# HBase Zookeeper AUTH_FAILED - Failed to find any Kerberos tgt

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

**Environment**

- `HBase 1.5`
- `Hadoop 2.9.2`
- `Zookeeper 3.5.6`

### Error

Receiving the following error after configuring Zookeeper to use Kerberos and configuring a HBase `jaas.conf` login config

... in `hbase-master.log`

```
ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: SASL authentication with Zookeeper Quorum member failed:
 javax.security.sasl.SaslException: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
 javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed 
               [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided 
                (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]) 
               occurred when evaluating Zookeeper Quorum Member's  received SASL token. 
               Zookeeper Client will go to AUTH_FAILED state.
```

**HBase jaas.conf**

```
 Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    useTicketCache=true
    storeKey=true
    keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.keytab"
    principal="hbase/@REALM.COM";
 };
```

**hbase-env.sh**

```sh
export HBASE_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/hbase/conf/jaas.conf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `hbase-env.sh`, hbase needs more than `java.security.auth.login.config` set in `HBASE_OPTS`.

Correct way to configure Zookeeper `jaas.conf`:

```sh
export HBASE_SERVER_JAAS_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/hbase/conf/jaas.conf"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/hbase/conf/jaas.conf"
```

If you have separate keytabs between your `master` and `region` you'll need two JAAS files and you must specify both

- `HBASE_SERVER_JAAS_OPTS`
- `HBASE_MASTER_OPTS`

If you use only 1 kerberos principal for all of hbase you only need to set `HBASE_SERVER_JAAS_OPTS`